# How to protect access to a folder or a disk-drive from all platforms (OSs) ?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, privacy-protection

I have an external hard disk which I want to protect access to (some of) its data (using password or a specific authentification procedure). (I would prefer folder protection rather that a full disk drive protection)

I want an effective solution that makes its data inaccessible for all users from all platforms (OS X, Windows, Linux distributions) using a software application (I use OS X).

Comment: Use Encryption - FileVault on mac should work. Any other OS could just read any file on the drive. If eCryptFS or EncFS works for mac that's an idea too

Comment: an encrypted .dmg would do it. Totally inaccessible on anything other than Mac, & on Mac needs the password. [& expandable, if needed, don't need to set a fixed size beforehand] Once decrypted, treat it like any 'disk' until you put it away again.

Answer (score 0):

TrueCrypt works nicely and is cross-platform. I still use it for encrypted file containers.

Yes, I know there are concerns about its "real" security and development has stopped on it, but it is still (one of) the best I've seen.

There are also others very similar but I don't have a lot of experience with those. Such as AxCrypt.